# Does $\det(I+A(I+B)^{-1})=\det(I+A^*(I+B)^{-1})$ hold for $A,B$ positive semi-definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, determinant

Is

$$\det(I+A(I+B)^{-1})=\det(I+A^*(I+B)^{-1})$$
where $I$ is identity matrix, $A,B$ are positive semi-definite complex valued matrices and $A^*$ is the conjugate (Hermitian) transpose of $A$.

Thanks a lot in advance.
 Question related to [Possible matrix-determinant identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516564/possible-matrix-identities)

Comment: We don't usually care whether something's homework or not. What's way more important is to show some self work, some ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complex matrices, positive-semi definite implies hermitian. So $A^*=A$.

**Edit:** see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516533/symmetric-vs-positive-semidefinite/516559?noredirect=1#comment1106702_516559) for a proof.